# background-color returns transparent in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, background-color

I can't figure out why IE is returning 'transparent' as my background-color?

```
$('.pulltab').each(function () {
    var bg = $(this).siblings('.top-thumbnail').css('background-color');
    alert(bg);
    $(this).css('background-color', bg);
});
```

I went so far as to parse into a hex value, but to no avail. I can't even get an alert to fire then, even though no errors are thrown :/

Some html:

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
   <div class="top-thumbnail border_GREEN">
      <img src="images/graphic.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   <div class="pulltab">
       <img src="images/right-carat-transparent-icon.png" alt="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and sample CSS:

```
.border_RED {background-color: #fc4247;}
.border_BLUE {background-color: #005596;}
.border_TEAL {background-color: #00b6c1;}
.border_ORANGE {background-color: #f58426;}
.border_GREEN {background-color: #88c755;}
```

The divs get a color class depending on what's selected. The function applies that color to the background of the .png container. IE throws transparent for each alert...Kind of stumped. Works fine everywhere else of course.

Comment: There are many versions of IE. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in IE 7 & 8: http://jsfiddle.net/cFcUG/

Comment: IE version? i get fine results in IE8/7, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/5WJT2/).

Comment: Yep, totally works in the fiddle. Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: So, fwiw, this thing is using CSS3 PIE for some fallback stuff...If it's accidentally applied to the same selector multiple times, it'll break stuff. Thanks for letting me know my code was ok, cheers